# Delphi Anonymous Functions with SetTimer API throws "privileged instruction" exception

Tags: api, delphi, exception, methods, anonymous

I'm struggling with some anonymous methods in Delphi.

When a call the Execute method and the timer created inside that method timeout, it throws a "privileged instruction" exception.

Is that because my anonymous function go out of scope?

```
unit OneShotTimerReloaded;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes;

type
  IOneShotTimerReloaded = interface
    ['{51DE72F0-4784-4CEB-A065-0B64D6EEA626}']

    procedure Execute(Proc: TProc; TimeOut: Cardinal = 1000); overload;
    procedure Execute(Proc: TProcedure; TimeOut: Cardinal = 1000); overload;
    procedure Execute(Event: TNotifyEvent; TimeOut: Cardinal = 1000; Sender: TObject = nil); overload;
  end;

  TOneShotTimerReloaded = class(TInterfacedObject, IOneShotTimerReloaded)
  public
    procedure Execute(Proc: TProc; TimeOut: Cardinal = 1000); overload;
    procedure Execute(Proc: TProcedure; TimeOut: Cardinal = 1000); overload;
    procedure Execute(Event: TNotifyEvent; TimeOut: Cardinal = 1000; Sender: TObject = nil); overload;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

{ TOneShotTimerReloaded }

procedure TOneShotTimerReloaded.Execute(Proc: TProc; TimeOut: Cardinal);
var
  TimerID: UIntPtr;

begin
  TimerID := SetTimer(HWND(0), 0, TimeOut, @procedure
    begin
      if (Assigned(Proc)) then
        Proc;

      KillTimer(HWND(0), TimerID);
    end
  );
end;

procedure TOneShotTimerReloaded.Execute(Proc: TProcedure; TimeOut: Cardinal);
var
  TimerID: UIntPtr;

begin
  TimerID := SetTimer(HWND(0), 0, TimeOut, @procedure
    begin
      if (Assigned(Proc)) then
        Proc;

      KillTimer(HWND(0), TimerID);
    end
  );
end;

procedure TOneShotTimerReloaded.Execute(Event: TNotifyEvent; TimeOut: Cardinal; Sender: TObject);
var
  TimerID: UIntPtr;

begin
  TimerID := SetTimer(HWND(0), 0, TimeOut, @procedure
    begin
      if (Assigned(Event)) then
        Event(Sender);

      KillTimer(HWND(0), TimerID);
    end
  );
end;

end.
```

The way I'm currently using this class is:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  t1: TOneShotTimerReloaded;
  t2: TOneShotTimerReloaded;

begin
  t1 := TOneShotTimerReloaded.Create;
  t2 := TOneShotTimerReloaded.Create;

  t1.Execute(btn1Click, 5000, btn1);
  t2.Execute(procedure begin ShowMessage('Anonymous'); end, 2000);

  // Not worried with t1 and t2 memory leaks yet!!! ;)
end;
```

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To start with, you're passing the address of the procedure as the callback for the timer (with the `@`),, and there is no code behind that address when the callback is invoked. I'm not aware of any way you can use anonymous methods as a Windows callback function. Your procedure also doesn't meet the definition of [TimerProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  that's required by `SetTimer`.

Comment: That's why my original implementation was storing the methods.

Answer (score 6):

You **cannot** use an anonymous procedure for a Win32 API callback, any more than you can use a non-static class method (without writing a proxy stub), or a local inner function (not safely, anyway).  An anonymous procedure is implemented as a compiler-generated reference-counted interface that has a hidden `Invoke()` method that is executed whenever the procedure is called.  That does not match the signature that `SetTimer()` (or any other API) is expecting for its callback.

Your code is essentially (but not exactly) doing the following behind the scenes:

```
type
  TOneShotTimerReloaded_Execute_AnonProc = interface(IInterface)
    procedure Invoke;
  end;

  TOneShotTimerReloaded_Execute_AnonProc_Impl = class(TInterfacedObject, TOneShotTimerReloaded_Execute_AnonProc)
  public
    Captured_Proc: ^TProc;
    Captured_TimerID: ^UIntPtr;
    procedure Invoke;
  end;

procedure TOneShotTimerReloaded_Execute_AnonProc_Impl.Invoke;
begin
  if (Assigned(Captured_Proc^)) then
    Captured_Proc^();

  KillTimer(HWND(0), Captured_TimerID^);
end

procedure TOneShotTimerReloaded.Execute(Proc: TProcedure; TimeOut: Cardinal);
var
  TimerID: UIntPtr;
  AnonProc: TOneShotTimerReloaded_Execute_AnonProc;
begin
  AnonProc := TOneShotTimerReloaded_Execute_AnonProc_Impl.Create;
  AnonProc.Captured_Proc := @Proc;
  AnonProc.Captured_TimerID := @TimerID;
  TimerID := SetTimer(HWND(0), 0, TimeOut, @AnonProc);
end;
```

See why it cannot possibly ever work?

Even if it were possible, your anonymous procedures are missing the input parameters that `SetTimer()` passes to its callback, as well as the `stdcall` calling convention, so you would be mismanaging the call stack anyway.

Your use of the `@` address operator is hiding compiler errors from you.  Get rid of `@` and let the compiler fail. That should have been your first indication that you are doing something wrong.

To do what you are attempting, you are going to have to create a dynamic proxy stub (similar to what `Classes.MakeObjectInstance()` does) so `SetTimer()` can call your `Proc` handlers (almost) directly.  Anonymous procedures will not help you with that.